# How to read nr of queries executed using Behat and Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, behat

I would like to start Behat-ing my application and would like to see nr of queries executed per-page (in case I forgot some Join statement and Doctrine lazy-loads the relation).

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [Symfony2 Behat Extension](http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/index.html), you should be able to the just the same thing as [in Symfony2 functional tests](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/testing/profiling.html). Profiler is just a service which can easily be retrieved from the container:

```php
$profiler = $kernel->getContainer()->get('profiler');
```

Then you'll need to load the profile for your response:

```php
$response = $session->getClient()->getResponse();
$token = $response->getHeader('X-Debug-Token');
$profile = $profiler->loadProfile($token);
```

It is also possible to load the profile from `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` object:

```
$profile = $profiler->loadProfileFromResponse($response);
```

However, `$session->getClient()->getResponse()` returns a `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response`.